# Geocache inside of a pole

Tags: geocaching

I'm trying to mount a geocache on a string inside a pole that looks like this:

[image: pole]

Can you suggest me an idea **how to attach the string to the pole without drilling anything to the pole**?

The dimensions are:

- Width: 44,5 mm
- Height: 49,5 mm
- Depth: about 70 cm

**Also, what can I do to secure it from falling down (the pole is hollow)?**

Comment: What about a rubber cork? it seems to angle upwards so push it in, push a cork into the end voila!

Comment: Frist you should ask yourself: "Why is there this hole?" If it is e.g. for water draining, it wont be the best idea to plug it.

Comment: Tie your string to a wad of duct tape and stuff it in the hole.

Comment: @Liam I instantly thought of that idea, but I don't know how to make it, and, would be difficult to mask so that _muggles_ don't spot it.

Comment: You could paint it/get a concrete grey one?

Comment: I don't have a "concrete grey" color, and even if I tried to paint it with something very close to the pole's color, it wouldn't be hard to spot.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's actually a 45mm hole, drill bits don't drill ovals, The hole was drilled at an angle, so the outer edge is an ellipse, but the hole itself will only 45mm in diametre.

Answer (score 5):

What's the width of the hole? I'm thinking of a mounting system like a wall socket. Spread it aginst the inner surface. Then tie the cach on it.

Or the very low cost variant:
Just use a piece of wire and bend it accordingly

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A hook/eyelet toggle bolt could work, depending on the weight of the cache:

[image]

If you unscrew the toggles and reverse them, the hook would be on the inside holding the string, and you would reach in with two fingers and squeeze the toggles to extract the cache. Much cheaper than a climbing cam, but the same idea!

Answer (score 4):

I think what I would use would be a **Rubber Washer**:

[image: Rubber Washer]

If you got a ~45mm rubber washer, you could tie your string to the washer, then put it into the hole one of two ways: either shove the washer in as deep as you can just to hold the string in place, or you could put your cache in first, then "plug" the hole with the washer. You could recess it completely in the hole so nothing is hanging out, it's black, so it won't draw a lot of attention from passers-by who may glance up into the dark hole in the pole, and the hole in the middle will make it easy for some one to stick their finger in it and pull it out.

Answer (score 3):

It already has a hole in it, what if you used a cam? Not exactly the cheapest method but potentially the easiest.

[image]

Edit: if you found the perfect size Tricam that might be a less expensive option

[image]

Comment: Wow, your must be very rich! That's set you back at least £60! Also it'd need to hang out so you could access the trigger. If you can't pull the trigger you won't get it out

Comment: That would stay there until *maybe* the next geocacher came by, then it would be **gone** and replaced by something else. But most likely someone would take it as climbing booty and leave your cache on the ground.